# How to install C++11 C++0x header files on Redhat Enterprise

Tags: c++, c++11, gnu, rhel

I moved my application to another Linux box, after compilation, it returns an error saying

```
#include <atomic>
```

can not be resolved.

I guess the new GNU C++11 header files / libraries are not installed on new machine.

My question is how can I install them?

I am running on Redhat Enterprise, so yum install ?

Thanks.

Comment: This RHEL 6? (Just making sure...)

Comment: What is your compiler version?

Comment: Have you added `--std=c++0x` or `--std=c++11` if GCC version is >= 4.7?

Comment: gcc (GCC) 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)

Comment: I have added --std=c++0x or --std=c++11

Comment: iirc , <atomic> wasn't there in gcc-4.4.x .

Comment: @manasij7479, how do I install gcc-4.6? Thanks.

Comment: Search the repo, rpmfusion..etc. If not present, build it yourself without rooting (otherwise it 'can' be a disaster).

Answer (score 8):

The [Red Hat Developer Toolset](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset/) provides C++11 support.

(Indeed, I suspect this is the primary reason for its existence.)

Comment: +1 Very nice.  There is a CentOS test version here: http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools/

Comment: Yes, but you should still be careful about mixing binaries built in C++11 mode with binaries built with an older compiler in C++98 mode. [Reference](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_developer_toolset/7/html/user_guide/sect-GCC-CPP#sect-GCC-CPP-Compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

The include under the version of gcc that comes with RHEL 6 is:

```
#include <cstdatomic>
```

See Runtime Library (libstdc++) section of [gcc 4.4 releaste notes](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/changes.html).

EDIT: This answer is not fully correct, because `cstdatomic` is the C11 file and not the C++11 one. For full C++ support in RHEL 6, the [devtoolset](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset/) should be used.

Comment: Interesting, but that is not the same thing as C++11 `<atomic>`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185734/.

Comment: @Nemo, in fact it's very similar, the answers to the question you link to are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll need to install an up to date version of GCC yourself; RHEL (at least as of 6.x) does not have a version of GCC supporting C++0x in it's repositories. You can build recent versions of GCC by following [GCC's installation instructions](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/), which are distribution-neutral.

You may also be able to use a package from a more recent **Fedora** release, which generally contains more "bleeding edge" software than that available in RHEL.