# What's the difference between "atomic" and "cstdatomic"?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

can someone please clarify the difference between the include options
`#include <atomic>` and `#inlucde <cstdatomic>`?

I'm guessing that there is none, because its the same behaviour?

I am asking this because on my debian system I've got only the atomic and on my kubuntu system I've got the cstdatomic.

- compiler on Debian: version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-4)
- compiler on Kubuntu: version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)

Comment: Well, what's the difference between `cstdio` and `iostream`? Of course it's more or less the same functionality, but one is proper C++ and the other is C legacy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<atomic>` is the C++ atomic operations library.

`<cstdatomic>` is the C++ version of the C atomic operations library.

Both will give you e.g., `std::atomic_char` but only the C++ version has `std::atomic<T>`.

As a general rule, C headers should be used in C++ by removing the `.h` extension and prepending `c` to the name: `stdatomic.h` becomes `cstdatomic`. That will include the C headers into the namespace `std`.

Note also that `stdatomic.h` (and `cstdatomic` hence) is C11 and `atomic` is C++11, which might explain the difference in compiler support.

Comment: @baam "Reverse general rule": a C++ header that looks like `<cxxx>` is probably the C++ equivalent of a C header `<xxx.h>`. :p

Comment: `stdatomic.h` comes from C11, not C99. Atomics were developed jointly by the C and C++ standards committees for the 2011 standards.

Answer (score 26):

Both existing answers are wrong, and most comments too.

`<cstdatomic>` is not a header defined in **any** standard.

It was defined in old C++0x drafts but is not in the final C++11 standard, only `<atomic>` is. So it was included as part of GCC 4.4's experimental C++0x support, but then renamed for later releases when it got renamed in the C++0x drafts (which was done in 2009 by [N2992](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2992.htm#header)).

You should not use `<cstdatomic>` unless you are stuck with GCC 4.4 and happy to use an incomplete and buggy version of C++11 atomics. (I have no idea why Kubuntu's GCC 4.6 includes the header, it is not in the upstream GCC 4.6 releases, it must be an Ubuntu or Kubuntu or Linaro patch.)

`<atomic>` is the standard C++11 header that you can rely on for any reasonably conforming C++11 implementation.

`<stdatomic.h>` is the C11 header, but the C++11 library is based on the C99 library, so does not include `<stdatomic.h>` and does not provide a `<cstdatomic>` corresponding to it.

Edit: Since C++23 there is a `<stdatomic.h>` header in the C++ library, but there's still no `<cstdatomic>`.

Comment: Supporting reference: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/changes.html - the old header was moved to the new name in libstdc++ shipped with GCC 4.5

Comment: Cppreference doesn't show any of the atomic_store and load functions that take  plain integers, but only `std::atomic` overloads. Does that mean in C++ I have to use `stdatomic.h` to use those, and are they even available in C++?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb `<atomic>` provides `std::atomic_store` and `std::atomic_load` but only for operating on `std::atomic` (and the aliases `std::atomic_int` etc.). Since C++23 there is also `<stdatomic.h>` which declares them in the global namespace too. But there have never been overloads for plain integers, only for atomic objects. That's the case in both C and C++. If you want to do atomic ops on plain ints in C++, use `std::atomic_ref<int>` to wrap it and then use the member functions of `std::atomic_ref`.