# How do I tell which version of g++ is the earliest version that uses `atomic` instead of `cstdatomic`?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have one system that runs `g++ 4.4.7` and only supports `#include <cstdatomic>`. I have another system that runs `g++ 4.9.1` and only supports `#include <atomic>`.

How can I discover the earliest version of `g++` that only supports `<atomic>`, or conversely the latest version of `g++` that supports `<cstdatomic>`, without building all the compilers and doing a manual search?

More broadly, how can I answer this question for arbitrary system header X?

Comment: It appears to be a difference between C++11 and older versions of C++.  The answers to this question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185734/whats-the-difference-between-atomic-and-cstdatomic

Comment: @Jonathan, It is absolutely a difference. The problem is that the versions of g++ progressively support more and more c++11 features but they do not document which headers are available in which version.

Comment: @Jonathan, the existing answers to that question where both wrong, so not much help :)

Comment: @merlin2011, that's not true, generally when a C++11 header was aded it is documented in the releases notes, e.g. [GCC 4.5](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/changes.html#cplusplus) added `<future>`, and `<random>`, and added the C++0x additions to `<functional>`. Those notes don't mention `<atomic>` because the header already existed, it was just renamed from <`cstdatomic>` to `<atomic>` to match a change in the C++0x draft.

Comment: I've just updated the [GCC 4.5 release notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/changes.html#cplusplus) to mention this header renaming.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [gcc git mirror](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GitMirror) where I would look for these things. `<cstdatomic>` first appears in April 2008 with [this commit](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commit;h=857d9b7bdf139c12a8bf7483f712f59cf047c698) and disappears in December 2009 with [this one](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commitdiff;h=2c122b5cc01648af54c0a51d9cb5fa0c74377826). As far as I can tell, `<atomic>` appears in that same commit. Looking at the [tags](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=tags), the latter is round about the time when gcc 4.5 was released, and sure enough, browsing through the source trees, `<cstdatomic>` disappears with 4.5 (but is kept in later 4.4 releases) and `<atomic>` appears in its place.

Addendum: The place to look in the source tree is `libstdc++v3/include/`. `<cstdatomic>` is in `c_global`, `<atomic>` in `std`.

Answer (score 0):

> More broadly, how can I answer this question for arbitrary system header X?

Wintermute shows the most reliable way, but you can also just check the release notes:

https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/changes.html#cplusplus
https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/changes.html#cplusplus
https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html#cplusplus
https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html#cxx
https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html#cxx
https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html#cxx
https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html#cxx

They don't always list *all* changes, but it might be much quicker than spelunking around the source repository.